# How to keep dropdownlist selected value after postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, postback

I m new in mvc development, i have 4 dropboxes and each dropdown triggers next dpdown object to bind values.

I bind gridview(codeplex mvc.grid) after all dropdownlist selected and click my button.

My question is :

How to save dropdownlist selected value after postback ?

Thanks for your helping

> View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Checklist", "Home"))
{`
<div>Dp1</div>
@Html.DropDownList("dpCompany", ViewBag.CompanyList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })

<div>Dp2</div>
@Html.DropDownList("dpBank", ViewBag.CompanyList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })

<div>Dp3</div>
@Html.DropDownList("dpStartCheckList", ViewBag.CompanyList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })

<div>>Dp4</div>
@Html.DropDownList("dpEndCheckList", ViewBag.CompanyList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })`

  <input type="submit" name="CheckList" value="DO" class="btn btn-default" />

}

  @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
  {
     columns.Add(c => c.customer_reference).Titled("Çek No").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.unvan).Titled("Ünvan").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.vergi_no).Titled("Vergi No").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.islem_tarihi).Titled("İşlem Tarihi").SetWidth(30).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
     columns.Add(c => c.currency).Titled("Para Birimi").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.full_curr_amount).Titled("Tutar").SetWidth(30).Format("{0:C}").Css("align-right");
  }).WithPaging(10)
```

> Script

```
$(function () {


                // Company
                $('#dpCompany').on('change', function () {
                    var stateDropdown = $('#dpBank');
                    //disable state drop down
                    stateDropdown.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    //clear drop down of old states
                    stateDropdown.empty();

                    //retrieve selected country
                    var company = $(this).val();
                    if (company.length > 0) {
                        // retrieve data using a Url.Action() to construct url
                        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetBankList")', {
                        company: company
                    })
.done(function (data) {
    //re-enable state drop down
    stateDropdown.removeAttr('disabled');
    //for each returned state
    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
        var values = state.split('|');
        //Create new option
        var option = $('<option value="' + values[0] + '" />').html(values[1]);
        //append state states drop down
        stateDropdown.append(option);
    });

    //if count 1 bind
    if ($("#dpBank option").length == 1) {
        $("#dpBank").trigger("change");
    }
})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
});} });
                //
                $('#dpBank').on('change', function () {
                    var stateDropdown = $('#dpCheckStart');
                    //disable state drop down
                    stateDropdown.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    //clear drop down of old states
                    stateDropdown.empty();

                    //retrieve selected country
                    var bank = $(this).val();

                    var company = $("#dpCompany").val();
                    if (company.length > 0) {
                        // retrieve data using a Url.Action() to construct url
                        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCheckList")', {
                        companyCode: company,
                        bankCode: bank
                    })
.done(function (data) {
    //re-enable state drop down
    stateDropdown.removeAttr('disabled');
    //for each returned state
    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
        var values = state.split('|');
        //Create new option
        var option = $('<option value="' + values[0] + '" />').html(values[1]);
        //append state states drop down
        stateDropdown.append(option);
    });

    //if count 1 bind
    if ($("#dpBank option").length == 1) {
        $("#dpCheckStart").trigger("change");
    }


})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
}) } });


                $('#dpCheckStart').on('change', function () {
                    var stateDropdown = $('#dpCheckEnd');
                    //disable state drop down
                    stateDropdown.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    //clear drop down of old states
                    stateDropdown.empty();

                    //retrieve selected country
                    var startOver = $(this).val();
                    if (startOver.length > 0) {
                        // retrieve data using a Url.Action() to construct url
                        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetListOver")', {
                        startOver: startOver
                    })
.done(function (data) {
    //re-enable state drop down
    stateDropdown.removeAttr('disabled');
    //for each returned state
    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
        var values = state.split('|');
        //Create new option
        var option = $('<option value="' + values[0] + '" />').html(values[1]);
        //append state states drop down
        stateDropdown.append(option);
    })

})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
})}});
```

> Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    ViewBag.Message = "";

    LoadDefaults();

    ViewBag.Loaded = false;
    return View();

}

private void LoadDefaults()
{
    ViewBag.BaseList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    ViewBag.CompanyList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    ViewBag.BankList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    ViewBag.AmountTotalTable = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult CheckList(FormCollection form)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "";

    ViewBag.StartSelectedItem = StartCheckNo = form["dpStartCheckList"];
    ViewBag.EndSelectedItem = EndCheckNo = form["dpEndCheckList"];


    F8BaseDB.DbSchema.F8BaseSchema.CheckList chk = new F8BaseDB.DbSchema.F8BaseSchema.CheckList();

    LoadDefaults();


    return View("Index", chk.GetAll(ViewBag.StartSelectedItem, ViewBag.EndSelectedItem));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, There are few ways to achieve this. If it's possible, I strongly suggest that you strongly type your view. This will enable you to access the posted form data easily rather than going through the `FormCollection`. This will also enable you to return the `Model` back to the view which will automatically select the company dropdown (which I assume is filled by default with all the companies and doesn't go through ajax to get them).

So, to answer your question. As like you get the values of `dpStartCheckList` and `dpEndCheckList`, store the values of the other two dropdowns as well in `ViewBag`. now in your view, do the following. save the values from viewbags to js variables

```
var selectedCompany = '@ViewBag.SelectedCompany'
var selectedBank = '@ViewBag.SelectedBank'
var startSelectedItem = '@ViewBag.StartSelectedItem'
```

and so on.

Now in each of the respective ajax `done` callbacks, after you add the items to the dropdownlist using `$.each` you set the respective value to the dropdown. for example, if you take the bank dropdown. after the `$.each`

```
$("#dpBank").val(selectedBank);
```

**UPDATE**
watch this youtube video, it talks about strongly typed views https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRinkoUpEEM

**UPDATE 2**
if you use this method, please remember to set the js variables to '' or undefined once you set it.

```
$("#dpBank").val(selectedBank);
selectedBank = '';
```

Otherwise it will select the same values from the dropdown in future ajax calls if that value is present in the options

Comment: thanks for ur answer. What do u advice to load dropdown items way,using model or using ajax bind ? If i choosed just asp.net this work was so easly.I want to use an update panel function in mvc.

Comment: Yes, I know. You feel like that when you start doing MVC. I also moved from ASP.Net Forms to MVC about 2 years ago and in my opinion, MVC is easier to me now. To answer your comment, it's personal preference and depend on how you decide to manage your code. using Ajax to load the options of nested dropdowns is good. The end product however is to get the values that user selected to the POST action so that you can save it to the database or do something with those values etc. For that part, it's easier for you to use the Model rather than going through the form collection.

Comment: To anyone who's doing MVC for the first time, I strongly suggest they go through the MSDN tutorials at least once, and also they provide access to some free pluralsight videos which helped me a lot in the beginning.

Comment: thx Amila. I moved to MVC last week and still i have headache about it,i improving myself on it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Html.DropdwonlistFor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClientID, new SelectList(Model.Clients, "ID", "ClientName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

where m.ClientID is the selected value

Comment: so how can i bind values from viewbag ?

Comment: You can populate the value from viewBag but to keep the value after postback its wise to use Model always.

Comment: I populate dropboxes using ajax method,how can keep values like that.i dont understand this. Can you give me a link about it. I want to do dropboxes like selecting city and county etx